# BroadcastReceiver class must work only when the toggle button is checked

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hey guys I want the `BroadcastReceiver` must work only when the `ToggleButton` is checked....
The code that i have used is...

In the `manifest.xml` file...

```
<receiver 
            android:name="Start">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

In the `Activity` class...

```
ToggleButton tgl;
    String prefs="app_preference";
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tgl=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tgl.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(prefs,MODE_PRIVATE);
        tgl.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED", false));

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(tgl.isChecked()){
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
             editor.putBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED", true);
                editor.commit();

        }else{
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED", false);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

in the `BroadcastReceiver` class...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean isEnabled = context.getSharedPreferences("app_preference",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("IS_RECEIVER_ENABLED",
                false);
        if (isEnabled) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Intent detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I am not getting this toast

Comment: Are you getting the toast if you place it outside the if-statement (is the problem the shared preference)

Comment: i got it i forgot to use usespermission

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if you register your receiver at Activity level(not Manifest) using

when toggle button is disable

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)
```

and when toggle button is disable you can Unregister it using..

```
unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)
```

Answer (score 0):

The receiver requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission. Add to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Please see [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) reference for more information.